# What video game is Charlie playing in Poker Face S01E07?

Tags: game-identification

In [season 1, episode 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Future_of_the_Sport) of the TV show *[Poker Face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_Face_(TV_series))* (2023), titled "[The Future of the Sport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Future_of_the_Sport)," the protagonist, Charlie (played by Natasha Lyonne), is shown playing an arcade stock car racing game.

The game appears to be from the 2000s, as its graphics and game design resemble games from that era. The monitor of the arcade cabinet does not appear to be a CRT monitor, which further supports this idea. The game features a minimap, and the player appears to be competing against a red [transparent "ghost" car](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RacingGhost), which may be a recorded run or a computer-controlled opponent.

Clips and screenshots of the game being played:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: screencap of the arcade cabinet]

The arcade cabinet and in-game banners bear the label "Rally Ridin'," but there appears to be no arcade racing game released under that title. I'm wondering if the arcade cabinet is a fake, but perhaps the game itself was based on a real racing game. It's possible that the creators of *Poker Face* took the "Rally Ridin'" name from the in-game banner signs of an actual game or maybe edited those signs in and used the same name to label the fake arcade cabinet.

[As commented by @JourneymanGeek](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/401833/what-video-game-is-charlie-playing-in-poker-face-s01e07?noredirect=1#comment564233_401833), it seems that the "Rally Ridin'" arcade cabinet is based on the *Nascar Racing* arcade cabinet. The designs are strikingly similar,  and the "82" marking has even been retained in the "Rally Ridin'" arcade cabinet. However, the game itself seems to be different from the *Nascar Racing* arcade game.

[image]

<sup>Image source: [arcadeclassics.com.au](https://arcadeclassics.com.au/arcade_games/drving_games/nascar-racing/)</sup>

##### What video game is Charlie playing in *Poker Face* S01E07?

Comment: https://youtu.be/HNB-9QEGDrA looking at the internals of a similar machine, wouldn't take much to take a 'real' console and throw a fake game onto it.

Comment: The price for licensing a real game in a movie may be much higher than creating some visual effects.

Answer (score 19):

No hits for an arcade game called "Rally Ridin'", no explanation of the use of an existing IP in any recap of the episode.

No HUD whatsoever - no score, no time. A double reflection of the view from behind, which is quite expensive to draw, but both seem way too small to have any practical use..

The red transparent car could be a recording of a former playthrough, but for an actual opponent the design is peculiar.

**I believe it's a mockup.**

Comment: It also says Rally Ridin on the signs in the game, which would be hard to do if it was a real game with a fake name.

Comment: "No HUD whatsoever - no score, no time" - well, there *is* a minimap.

Comment: @adaliabooks I've thought about that too. I was thinking it's possible that the creators of *Poker Face* took inspiration from the "Rally Ridin'" in-game banner signs (of a possibly real game) and created a fake arcade cabinet with the same name.

Answer (score 14):

It's a mockup made for the show, using a rebadged cabinet.

The textures of the trees appear too hi-res and crisp for an early 2000's game, which typically opted for flat billboards, sometimes with two billboards forming a cross shape.  Usually the cross-shaped trees used the same texture on both billboards.

This was true even for contemporary arcade games, as home console hardware finally matched parity with arcade hardware.

Sometimes you would see cylindrical trunk trees, but they would still feature flat, super-compressed leaves to compensate.

The inertia in the second GIF feels forced and inconsistent, like the animation's pathing was drawn by hand.

Having one mirror is resource intensive, but two?  And neither serve much function but decorative, so decorative it is.

Also I feel like having an onscreen steering wheel is redundant, when your player character has a steering wheel.

Comment: Very good additional points on the trees and the completely useless graphical steering wheel (although the latter could be argued to be the result of a lazy port :).